# Why elements are not appearing above the Hiro marker in ar.js?

Tags: google-maps-markers, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm using ar.js and a-frame framework to try augmented reality. And I have a simple problem : my elements are not appearing right above the marker in the scene (they are all shifted downwards).
So I decided to come back to a simply html file that show a box above the marker and when the marker appears, the box is shifted downwards (it seems to be a y-axis problem since z and x positions seem ok).
Does anyone had already gone through such thing ? thanks for your help
Heres is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./aframe-ar.js"></script>
</head>

    <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <a-scene>
            <a-marker preset="hiro" emitevents="true">
                <a-box position='0 0 0' material='opacity: 0.5'></a-box>
            </a-marker>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdrrT.png)

and here is my console log when project is initialized:

```
[Log] A-Frame Version: 1.3.0 (Date 2022-02-04, Commit #cc3516ce) (aframe.min.js, line 45273)
[Log] THREE Version (https://github.com/supermedium/three.js): – "^0.137.0" (aframe.min.js, line 45273)
[Log] WebVR Polyfill Version: – "^0.10.12" (aframe.min.js, line 45273)
[Log] starting... (index.js, line 1)
[Log] core:component:warn The component `markerhandler` was registered in a <script> tag after the scene. Component <script> tags in an HTML file should be declared *before* the scene such that the component is available to entities during scene initialization.  (aframe.min.js, line 19)
[Log] AR.js – "3.4.5" – "- trackingBackend:" – "artoolkit" (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] ARjs.Anchor - – "changeMatrixMode:" – "modelViewMatrix" – "/ markersAreaEnabled:" – false (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Warning] ArMarkerControls: 'markersAreaEnabled' is not a property of this material. (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Info] ARToolkit  – "0.3.0" (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] [ARController] – "ARToolkit initialized" (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] [ARController] – "Camera params loaded with ID" – 0 (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Warning] [info] Allocated videoFrameSize 1228800 (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] [ARController] – "Got ID from setup" – 0 (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Warning] [info] Pattern detection mode set to 1. (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Warning] [info] Pattern ratio size set to 0.500000. (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Warning] [info] Labeling mode set to 1 (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] actual source dimensions – 1440 – 480 (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] source orientation – "landscape" (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] actual source dimensions – 1440 – 480 (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
[Log] source orientation – "landscape" (aframe-ar.js, line 1)
```

I've tried severals thing with  or  attributes but nothing worthy. also tried in chrome and safari browser nothing changed.